# Drupal 6 Views - Don't display a row if one field is empty

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Is it possible not to display a Views row if one of its constituent fields is empty?

In my case I have a list of users with their username and picture, and I only want to display those users who have uploaded an image.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a filter to your view.

Add the filter `User: Picture` and for **Has Avatar** check "Yes", click update and save your view to see the changes.  Users who don't have a profile picture will not show up in the view.

Comment: In my case the picture is a CCK field BUT I have a module that converts this into the User picture so it might work... I'll have a go.

Comment: @james you can use the same idea for a CCK field as well. Add a filter for the field (say you're using an imagefield), and check _true_ so that only rows that contain a picture in that field will be shown

Comment: It's bizarre how with all the complicated stuff I've done with Views I can forget about things like this! Cheers, works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I only have a few mins, so I didn't have a chance to test this.
For the general question is it possible not to display a Views row if one of its constituent fields is empty.

Row style: Fields
Row style options - Hide empty fields

Add all the (non-picture) fields for the row, and "Exclude from display"
Then have the picture field be the last field so it can use the replacement patterns for all the other fields.

For the Picture options, "Hide if empty".
"Rewrite the output of this field" and add the html and "Replacement patterns" for the all the fields in the Text box.

Comment: Because of the way I'm doing the rows (in a table) I don't think this'll work in my particular situation, but thanks for the idea. I may come back to it!